How do I load my custom trained DAMO-YOLO model?
I am used to loading YOLO models with: "model=YOLO('best.pt')", where I initialize "YOLO" using "from ultralytics import YOLO".
However, I am looking into computer vision models with open source licenses, DAMO-YOLO is what I'm testing currently.
I have trained a custom model based off the Tiny (L20-T) model from their Model Zoo. The model is a ".pth" file, there is also an "ONNX" version which I have converted from the ".pth" file.
I tried -
model = torch.load(model_path, map_location=torch.device('cpu'))
model.eval()

but I'm getting an error as seen below -
<module>
    model.eval()
    ^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'eval'

How do I load this model to use in my program? Any help is massively appreciated.

After training the model, how did you save it? How did you create your pth file?
